# Syntax Error : Bad Token " " in Codeskulptor

Tags: python

I am wondering what is wrong with my code? I am using python 3.0 (NVM GOT IT)

```
import random
random.seed(1,10)
a = random.randint (1,10)
b = random.randint (1,10)
print("What is: " + str(a) + " X " + str(b) + "?")  
ans = int(input("Your answer: "))  
if (a * b == ans):  
print ("Correct!")  
else:  
print ("Incorrect!")
```

Comment: can you post the error and your if-else statements also not indented

Comment: it's working for me

Comment: I am sorry I am new at this website and python here is the code https://py3.codeskulptor.org/#user305_tBGw6DwP4A_0.py it gives me an error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given the code, I can only think of indentation error. Please see below, it works-

```
import random
random.seed(1)

a = random.randint(1, 10)
b = random.randint(1, 10)

print("What is: {} X {}?".format(a, b))
ans = int(input("Your answer: "))
if (a * b == ans):
    print("Correct!")
else:
    print("Incorrect!")
```

See a screenshot as well-

[image]

[Here](https://onlinegdb.com/rJHXi2QqL) is the URL to access the IDE.

Comment: I always use `seed` with one argument. This is the syntax `random.seed(a=None, version=2)`. See [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html) to know why your code worked, fortunately! Anyway, please remove the second argument.